# setOverrideDeadline() doesn't seem to have an effect

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I've got an app widget where I want to maintain up-to-date information in a line of text that says "x minutes ago", referring to the age of the bitmap below it. I wrote the code as follows:

```
private fun scheduleUpdateAge(context: Context) {
    val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    val resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(
            JobInfo.Builder(UPDATE_AGE_JOB_ID, ComponentName(context, UpdateAgeService::class.java))
                    .setMinimumLatency(MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                    .setOverrideDeadline(2 * MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                    .build())
    reportScheduleResult("update age", MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, resultCode)
}
```

In the last line i check the result of scheduling, it's always successful.

In the job service I update the remote views and then reschedule the job:

```
class UpdateAgeService : JobService() {
    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        MyLog.i("UpdateAgeService start job")
        updateRemoteViews(applicationContext)
        jobFinished(params, false)
        scheduleUpdateAge(applicationContext)
        return false
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        MyLog.i("UpdateAgeService stop job")
        return true
    }
}
```

However, I keep observing that Android has not invoked my job for much longer periods, above ten minutes. At that time the other scheduled job, the one that refreshes the bitmap, kicks in and resets the age text as well.

The documentation on `setOverrideDeadline` states

> Set deadline which is the maximum scheduling latency. The job will be run by this deadline even if other requirements are not met.

but Android seems to violate it.

Am I missing something here?

---

I'm aware that the "natural" way to schedule periodic jobs is `setPeriodic()`, but `setPeriodic()` wasn't invoking my job either and its contracts clearly states

> You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

So missing the schedule is "by the book" for that case.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, basically when the phone is locked, scheduled tasks get invoked very rarely no matter what you set. The only option is using an `AlarmManager` but that's pretty aggressive, I didn't even try it but probably it'll produce an icon on the status bar. Also, in the Play Console your app shows up as "bad behavior" if it causes more than 10 wakeups per hour.